# How to send email with Do Not Forward flag using exchangelib

Tags: python, email, exchangelib

This is similar to [How to set/access outlook DoNotForward property in Microsoft exchange service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36067768/how-to-set-access-outlook-donotforward-property-in-microsoft-exchange-service) but I want to use the exchangelib Python module to send emails.

Comment: Do you want to find out *how* to send emails?

Answer (score 4):

The building blocks and links to documentation are available in this exhangelib issue: https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/issues/540

In short, it's really tricky to do if you are not using a Microsoft-supplied library. You have to build a binary message with all sorts of magic variables and send that as a custom extended property. *Plus* you have to implement the client-side encryption needed by EWS rights management.

AFAIK, no-one has attempted a Python solution yet, and a full solution would require quite a bit of work.